# SSL Certificate authentication and and C#

Tags: c#

I have a certificate with this information :

> This certificate is intended for the following purpose(s) :
>     - Prove your identity to a remote computer
>     - Ensures the identity of remote computer

The certificate is already installed on my server, and I have to use it to call a soap web service. 
But when I try to call this web service, a have this error :

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Someone told me that `"certifcate exchnage is not happening from my end"` 
What does that mean?

**server Configuration**

- IIS 8.5
- Windows server 2012 r2

  IDE visual studio 2017

  ```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
      {

          Back2uSubscribeManageService client = null;
          string certName = string.Empty;
          RemoteCertificateValidationCallback 
          chainedServerCertValidationCallback = null;


   public Form1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              chainedServerCertValidationCallback = 
              ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
              ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new 
          RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnValidateServerCertificate);

          }

  //below the method where I call a method of the web service

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  X509Store computerCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, 
           StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
      computerCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = 
      computerCaStore.Certificates;
      X509Certificate2Collection findResult = 
     certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"*.mydomain.com", false);
              X509Certificate cert;
              cert = findResult[0];

  client = new Back2uSubscribeManageService();
  client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
  client.Url = url;
  var result = client.subscribeProduct(request);
  }
  }
  //below is the callback method for server certificate validation.

   bool OnValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
          {

              X509Store computerCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, 
                 StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
              X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = 
                computerCaStore.Certificates;
              X509Certificate2Collection findResult = 

    certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName,"xxxxx", false);
              X509Certificate cert;
              cert = findResult[0];

             bool valid = true;
             if (valid)
              {
                  if (chainedServerCertValidationCallback == null)
                  {
                      bool validationResult = 
                          certificate.Issuer.Equals(cert.Issuer);
                      return validationResult;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      return chainedServerCertValidationCallback(sender, 
                     certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors);
                  }
              }
              return false;
          }
      }
  ```

I expect a message tells me that the subscription was successful but I receive error message :

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Comment: Post the *full* exception, not just part of the message. Although the most likely cause is that you use an old .NET Framework version and trying to connect to a server that requires TLS1.2

Comment: TLS1.2 support was added in .NET 4.5. The oldest *supported* .NET Version is 4.5.2 so that shouldn't be a problem. Until 4.6 though you had to explicitly specify that you want to use TLS1.2. Starting with 4.6, the framework leaves the choice to the OS which means it will use the most secure TLS version available - TLS1.2 now, TLS1.3 in the future

Comment: *Older Windows versions* though may need registry tweaking or patching to enable TLS1.2 . Windows 2012R2 [definitely needs an update for that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi), something that was pushed through Windows Update years ago

Comment: Finally, none of this is new. After the Heartbleed worm almost all services started demanding TLS1.2 - banks, airlines, payment processors, GMail. By 2017 you couldn't connect to most business services without it. PCI requirements demand TLS1.2 since July 2018. If someone says "What about .NET 2?" or "we can't upgrade to .NET 4.7" well ... it's been 7 years since Heartbleed, 3 years since the 2016 cutoff by airlines and a full year since the PCI cutoff.